# How can I prevent stock reduction on netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am creating a sample sales order on Netsuite and I do not want it to affect the inventory. Is there a script that I can modify to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script but if you are wanting to approve the sales order and not have it commit inventory there is a `Commit` drop-down at the line-level that lets you select 'Do Not Commit'

If you need code the field Id is `commitinventory` and Do Not Commit has value 3 so a sample would be:

```
for( var i = soRec.getLineCount({sublistId:'item'})-1; i>= 0; i--){
  soRec.setSublistValue({
    sublistId:'item',
    fieldId:'commitinventory',
    value:3,
    line: i
  });
}
```

Comment: I am so grateful for your assistance. This has helped me alot.